# How to show foreign key strings related value in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, model, django-serializer

I get responses in foreign key values as shown below image

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBJam.png)

but I want the response of values in string which Is returned from **str** method in models file.

my models is given below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,AbstractBaseUser
from .Manager import Custom_Manager
# Create your models here.

class user_profile(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True,default='')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email_address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='Profile Pictures', blank=True)
    objects = Custom_Manager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email;


class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name;

class Services(models.Model):
    s_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    provider_user=models.ForeignKey('digi_khidmat.user_profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category=models.ForeignKey(to='digi_khidmat.Category',on_delete=models.CASCADE ,blank=True,null=True)
    Services_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='Services', blank=True,null=True)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    services_rate_per_hour=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.s_name

class request_services(models.Model):
    services = models.ForeignKey(to='digi_khidmat.Services',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="Services")
    provider_user = models.ForeignKey(to='digi_khidmat.user_profile',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="service_provider")
    category = models.ForeignKey(to='digi_khidmat.Category',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True )

    request_user = models.ForeignKey(to='digi_khidmat.user_profile',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="request_user")
    status=models.ForeignKey(to='digi_khidmat.services_status',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="request_user")

class services_status(models.Model):
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,default='Pending')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status;
```

my Serializer class is below

```
class user_profile_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=user_profile
        fields='__all__'


class Category_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields='__all__'

class Services_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Services
        fields='__all__'

class Services_status(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=services_status
        fields='__all__'


class request_services_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serviese_name=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=request_services
        fields='__all__'
```

when i convert

```
 serviese_name=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

to

```
 serviese_name=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)
```

it throws the following error

```
ceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\Django\djangoProject\digi_khidmat\ServicesRequest.py", line 14, in get
    return Response(services_serializer.data)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 502, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 538, in get_attribute
    relationship = get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Muhammad Arshad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 97, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
AttributeError: 'request_services' object has no attribute 'serviese_name'
[01/Mar/2022 14:29:00] "GET /api/sr1 HTTP/1.1" 500 125633
```

example
expected response

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "services": Learn Piano,
        "provider_user": User1 email,
        "category": Music,
        "request_user": user2 email,
        "status": pending/cancel/approved
    },
```

but the response I get from the server

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "services": 2,
        "provider_user": 1,
        "category": 2,
        "request_user": 2,
        "status": 1
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to set `many=True`: you want to work with a `ForeignKey`, so that means you serialize a single object.

What you need to do is use the name of the `ForeignKey`s, so:

```
class request_services_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    services = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    provider_user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    request_user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    status= serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model=request_services
        fields='__all__'
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`services_status`</s> to `serviceStatus`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Service` instead of <s>`Services`</s>.